# fadein and fadeout in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi i'm hive a popup that appear's with fade In and close with fadeout. The problem it's when do the fadeout animation also makes a post back i don't want that, i want that works like the property `CancelControlID` in the model popUp.

**note**

i can't set the property `CancelControlID` to the close button because then doesn't do the animation

**see the code**

**the Button**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewPopUp" CssClass="btnNewPopUp" runat="server" Text="Crear Capas"/>
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="true" OkControlID="btnOk" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopUpSetLayers" id="mdlPopUp" TargetControlID="btnNewPopUp" >
            </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

**the Panel**

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopUpSetLayers" runat="server" CssClass="popUp" > 
    <table id="tbl" class="tableFinder">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="header1">Crear capas</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLayerName" CssClass="formatText" runat="server" Text="Nombre de la Capa"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" /> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close Me" /> 
</asp:Panel>
```

**the animations**

```
<asp:AnimationExtender id="MyExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnNewPopUp">
    <Animations>
        <OnClick>
            <FadeIn AnimationTarget="pnlPopUpSetLayers" Duration=".5" Fps="20" />
        </OnClick>
    </Animations>
</asp:AnimationExtender>

<asp:AnimationExtender id="AnimationExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnClose">
    <Animations>
        <OnClick>
            <FadeOut AnimationTarget="pnlPopUpSetLayers" Duration=".5" Fps="20" />
        </OnClick>
    </Animations>
</asp:AnimationExtender>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally hate the animation extenders...have you thought about changing to jQuery?  If so, the JavaScript would be as easy as this:

```
jQuery('#<%=pnlPopUpSetLayers.ClientID %>').fadeIn();
jQuery('#<%=pnlPopUpSetLayers.ClientID %>').fadeOut();
```

Comment: hi, i'm tried but it's not get doesn't work are you sure about how is the selector??

Answer (score 1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .panel{display: none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnShowPanel').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#pnlHelloWorld').fadeIn('slow');
        });

        $('#btnClose').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#pnlHelloWorld').fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowPanel" Text="Show" runat="server" />

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlHelloWorld" CssClass="panel" runat="server">
        Hello World!<br />

        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" Text="Close" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
```